# `powershell -version` doesn't work on Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, powershell

I have just installed [the open-source version of PowerShell for Linux](http://github.com/powershell/powershell) on Arch Linux using [the *powershell-git* package](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages/powershell-git/) from [AUR](http://aur.archlinux.org). When I try PowerShell's `-Version` functionality, I get the following:

```
PS /home/user> powershell -Version 5.1                                          
-Version : The term '-Version' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -Version 5.1
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Version:String) [], CommandNot 
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to fix this?

Comment: use the ` $PSVersionTable.PSVersion` command.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell was written for Windows, which assumes an underlying filesystem where case does not matter.  When you enter a PowerShell command, the program reads whatever you type, and then matches it against its idea of what the case *ought* to be and redisplays that.

The [help-message for PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/resources/ManagedEntranceStrings.resx#L128) shows the option as **`-Version`**:

```
-Version
    Starts the specified version of Windows PowerShell. 
    Enter a version number with the parameter, such as "-version 2.0".
```

The error message is saying that it expected to find a match using the filesystem's notion of the fully-spelled name.  You will probably have better success if you use the mixed-case names as indicated in the help-message.

Comment: This does not work either.

Comment: Raise a bug report.   It is an alpha release, after all.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu [seems](https://askubuntu.com/q/1007024/45156) to work fine:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ pwsh
PowerShell v6.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion                                                                              

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleas BuildLabel 
                     eLabel               
-----  -----  -----  --------- ---------- 
6      0      1                           


PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> get-host                                                                                               


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 6.0.1
InstanceId       : 914b71f4-0e73-461c-b1c3-f04753e5ed34
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-CA
CurrentUICulture : en-CA
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace



PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> $PSVersionTable                                                                                        

Name                           Value                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                   
PSVersion                      6.0.1                                                                                   
PSEdition                      Core                                                                                    
GitCommitId                    v6.0.1                                                                                  
OS                             Linux 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 25 09:13:46 UTC 2018                     
Platform                       Unix                                                                                    
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                 
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                     


PS /home/thufir> 
PS /home/thufir> exit                                                                                                   
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ pwsh hello_world.ps1 
hello powershell world
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ./hello_world.ps1 
hello powershell world
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat hello_world.ps1 
#!/usr/bin/pwsh -Command


"hello powershell world"
thufir@dur:~$
```

you'll have to clarify the problem.  You can't find the version for `pwsh`?